# Am I able to use parallel STL algorithms from C++17/C++20 in Matlab MEX functions?

Tags: c++, matlab, std, dynamic-linking, mex

I am putting together a minimal example leveraging [parallelism features in C++17/20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism) within Matlab MEX functions. I am able to compile and run the mex function from Matlab, but when I set the [execution policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/execution_policy_tag_t) of my C++ STL function to "par" instead of "seq", Matlab gives a runtime linkage complaint. Code and error message follows:

test.m (Matlab top-level script):

```
vec_in = zeros(5);
coeff = 0.05;

vec_out = test_mex_gateway(vec_in, coeff);
```

test_mex_gateway.cpp (C++ interface to Matlab):

```
#include "mex.h"

extern void test_execute(float *array_in, float *array_out, const size_t vec_size, const float coeff);

void mexFunction( int nlhs,
                  mxArray *plhs[],
                  int nrhs,
                  const mxArray *prhs[] )
{
    // Check for proper number of input and output arguments
    if( nrhs != 2 )
    {
        mexErrMsgTxt( "3 input arguments required: input_data, coeff" );
    }

    if( nlhs > 2 )
    {
        mexErrMsgTxt( "Too many output arguments." );
    }

    const mwSize *matlab_data_dims_in;
    mwSize matlab_data_dims_out[1];

    // Input Parameters
    float *input_data = (float *) mxGetData(prhs[0]);
    float coeff = mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);

    // Get dimensions
    matlab_data_dims_in = mxGetDimensions(prhs[0]);
    const int vec_len = matlab_data_dims_in[1];

    // Set output data dimension
    matlab_data_dims_out[0] = vec_len;

    // Output data
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(1, matlab_data_dims_out, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    float *output_data = (float *) mxGetData(plhs[0]);

    test_execute(input_data, output_data, vec_len, coeff);

}
```

test_execute.cpp (This is where the actual C++ STL call is made):

```
#include <execution> // std::execution::*
#include <numeric>   // std::exclusive_scan()

void test_execute(float *array_in, float *array_out, const size_t vec_size, const float coeff)
{
    std::exclusive_scan
    (
        std::execution::par, // std::execution::seq works here for Mex call, par does not
        array_in,
        array_in + vec_size,
        array_out,
        0.0f,
        [coeff](float a, float b)
        {
            float ret = a + b + coeff;
            return ret;
        }
    );
}
```

I also have a stand-alone main function to replace the Mex wrapper to do a pure C++ test, test_standalone.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

size_t VEC_NUM_ELEM = 10;

extern void test_execute(float *array_in, float *array_out, const size_t vec_size, const float coeff);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Try: " << argv[0] << "<coeff>" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    const float coeff = std::stof(argv[1]);

    std::cout << "Coeff: " << coeff << std::endl;

    float __attribute__ ((aligned (64))) *vec1_array = (float *)malloc(VEC_NUM_ELEM * sizeof(float));
    float __attribute__ ((aligned (64))) *vec2_array = (float *)malloc(VEC_NUM_ELEM * sizeof(float));

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < VEC_NUM_ELEM; i++)
    {
        vec1_array[i] = static_cast<float>(i);
    }

    test_execute(vec1_array, vec2_array, VEC_NUM_ELEM, coeff);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is how I am building and linking, build.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm *.o
rm *.exe
rm *.mexa64

cstd=c++17

gpp910=/home/m/compilers/bin/g++

tbblib=/home/m/reqs/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8

echo "Building test_execute.cpp..."
$gpp910 -std=$cstd -I/home/m/reqs/tbb/include -L$tbblib -ltbb -Wl,rpath=$tbblib -c test_execute.cpp -fPIC

echo "Building test_standalone.cpp..."
$gpp910 -std=$cstd -L$tbblib test_execute.o test_standalone.cpp -o test_standalone.exe -ltbb

echo "Building test_mex_gateway.cpp..."
mex test_execute.o test_mex_gateway.cpp -L$tbblib -ltbb
```

The parallel STL calls has a requirement to link against the Intel TBB (Threading Building Blocks), so before I run Matlab to call test.m OR before I run my test_standalone.exe, I run:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/m/reqs/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

I also make sure to make the the C++ library associated with the version of GCC we built with available at runtime:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/m/compilers/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

When I run test_standalone.exe, everything behaves normally whether I have the execution policy set to "par" or "seq" on std::exclusive_scan. When run test.m, if "seq" was compiled, I can run with no errors. If "par" was compiled, Matlab complains at runtime about a linkage issue:

*Invalid MEX-file 'test_mex_gateway.mexa64': test_mex_gateway.mexa64: undefined symbol:
_ZN3tbb10interface78internal20isolate_within_arenaERNS1_13delegate_baseEl*

I suspect this was a function that was supposed to be linked from TBB, which I confirmed:

$ nm /home/m/reqs/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8/libtbb.so.2 | grep baseEl

0000000000028a30 T _ZN3tbb10interface78internal20isolate_within_arenaERNS1_13delegate_baseEl

000000000005ed70 r _ZN3tbb10interface78internal20isolate_within_arenaERNS1_13delegate_baseEl$$LSDA

I confirmed Matlab's LD_LIBRARY_PATH has the path I supplied in the above "export .." to this library.

I tried making sure my libraries came before the many Matlab-centric paths Matlab adds to LD_LIBRARY_PATH after it launches from the terminal.

I tried baking the path to the linked libraries via a -Wl,rpath=<path_to_tbb.so> passage to the linker.

After almost two days, I can't figure out why Matlab is having this very specific runtime issue, especially when the pure C++ version is not. Any help would be appreciated.

**RHEL 7.9**

**Matlab R2020a**

**GCC 9.1.0**

**TBB (Intel Thread Building Blocks) 2020.3**

Comment: `tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8` doesn't seem to match gcc 9.1.0. Don't you have a `tbb` installation in `/usr/lib*/libtbb*` (assuming that's where `gcc` would search if you didn't specify the `gcc4.8` directory)?

Comment: Sidenote: Instead of those `malloc`s (which I don't think will care about the alignment attribute you put on the pointer), you could use `auto vec1_array = new (std::align_val_t(64)) float[VEC_NUM_ELEM];` and `::operator delete[](vec1_array, std::align_val_t(64));`.

Comment: When you say "STL", you really mean to say "C++ Standard Library", no? "STL" stands for "Standard Template Library", and is an old library that some functionality in `std::` is based on. Why would code in `std::` need linking against a library (TBB) that is not part of the Standard Library? You don't ever include the headers for TBB, so you shouldn't need to link against the TBB library.

Comment: Anyway, in MATLAB, type `getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')`, and then type `!echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You'll see these are different. You need to ensure that the `getenv` call contains your library path, that's the one that matters.

Comment: The `-Wl,rpath=$tbblib` linker argument you pass to the first compile command is useless because you're generating an object file, the linker is never called here. Put that into your `mex` command instead. If it works correctly, you won't need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I noticed the gcc4.8 path as well, however, this is the only library available and it works in the pure C++ case (no Matlab) so I don't think this is the issue

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, I meant to say the "C++ Standard Library". It needs to be linked against TBB because the parallel execution of these algorithms rely on TBB. That's why you don't see me including headers -- they are included in the library code.

Yes, I mentioned in the post that I checked getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH') and confirmed the proper path was included there, yet it still wasn't working. That's the issue.

Comment: If it’s finding the library, it’s not able to load it because some dependency can’t be found. This could very well be the issue with MATLAB on Linux providing its own GCC runtime libraries. You have to make sure either all your MEX-file binaries and all its dependencies use a GCC equal or older to the one used to build MATLAB. Or you have to delete the GCC runtime in the MATLAB installation, if you have a never version installed globally.

Comment: This sounds the most likely cause to me. In order to use the parallel algorithms, I need at least a compiler that supports C++17, so that's GCC 9*. It's possible Matlab 2020a includes GCC runtime libraries that are older than this.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that Matlab comes with a version of libtbb.so included in its installation. From what I can tell, when launching a Mex file, Matlab will use its own libraries first, regardless of your LD_LIBRARY_PATH order. This is what was giving me runtime issues as a Mex file but not as a pure C++ file. Removing the libtbb.so from Matlab's installation directory allowed runtime linkage to find *my* version of libtbb, and I was able to run without errors. Thanks to Cris Luengo for pointing me in the right direction.